# Ng-If Not Applying In View

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to update the ng-if in my HTML, here:

```
<div id="shyBoxII"  ng-if="robot.robot" ng-class="background">
    <div class="row"><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i></div>
    <div class="row"><i class="fa fa-book"></i></div>
    <div class="row"><i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i></div>
    <div class="row"><i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i></div>
    </div>
```

But in my controller, I console log `robot.robot`, get it `true` and still `#shyBoxII` doesn't show up. What gives?

```
  $scope.pinActiveSection = function ($event,section) {
            var $element = $(".table-hover tr."+section+"");
            console.log($event,section);
            if($element.children(":first").hasClass("unlock")){
            $(".table-hover tr:not(."+section+")").fadeOut( "slow", function() {
            $(this).remove();
            $element.parent().parent().parent().css("top", "10%");
            $element.parent().parent().parent().css("padding", "0%");
            $scope.activeSection.activeSection = section;
            $scope.robot.robot = true;
            console.log($scope.robot.robot);
            if($scope.activeSection == "I")
            {
                $scope.background.push("I");
                $scope.background.push("show");
            }
            });
            }
            else{
                $.fn.extend({
            animateCss: function (animationName) {
                var animationEnd = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';
                $(this).addClass('animated ' + animationName).one(animationEnd, function() {
                    $(this).removeClass('animated ' + animationName);
                });
            }
        });
        $element.children(":first").animateCss('bounce');
            }
        };
```

To be clear, `$scope.pinActiveSection` is running, I see the console log that `$scope.robot.robot` is `true`, so I don't understand why my view doesn't update. If I push the `$scope.robot.robot` up in the `if` block then it works, but I want it as part of the `fadeOut` callback. Please help!

Edit: If I run `pinActiveSelection` twice in a row, I see the `#shyBoxII` after the second run. Does that give any clue as to what is going wrong the first time?

Comment: are you using this code in ng-repeat or normally?

Comment: @ShailendraSinghDeol normally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please add this code to the end of the function 'pinActiveSection'

`$scope.$apply();` Or `$scope.$digest();`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using ng-show?

```
<div id="shyBoxII"  ng-show="robot.robot" ng-class="background"></div>
```

Comment: try doing this on your html 
{{robot.robot}}
does it print anything?
do you have your controller defined on your html?

<div ng-controller="<insert controller name>">
 
</div>
?

Comment: @FrederickMfinanga {{robot.robot}} prints out `true`

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that Angular does not know the value of `$scope.robot.robot` is updated for the first time because no `$digest()` is triggered to compare the old value with the new value. Try to Use:

```
$timeout (function () {
    $scope.robot.robot = true;
})
```

Or use `$scope.$evalAsync()` instead of `$timeout()`.